# How to get specific data from this column data in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get the ("Houston, TX, USA","zipcode":"77002") from the database data below::

```
{
    "addressCount":"1",
    "link":"https:\/\/maps.googleapis.com\/maps\/api\/staticmap?center=Houston, TX, USA&zoom=16&size=175x124&maptype=roadmap&key=AIzaSyASx6y5K6jD0DATE2S7_UarIvRa3EN-C_M",
    "address":"Houston, TX, USA",
    "zipcode":"77002"
}
```

Comment: why is it downvoted I am asking a question that is essential.

Comment: Its not clear, do you want to do this with SQL code or having read this data using PHP do you want to get to those 2 fields from PHP. _Oh and thats why you are getting downvotes_

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the 
[Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: This data is what I need to extract. 
Houston,TX, USA,"zipcode":"77002

Comment: YESSssss we get that. Is this data ALL in a JSON Column type in your table? That would allow you to query the specific data. If not, then you have to read the column, convert it to PHP data using `JSON_DECODE()` and then pick the bit out you want

Comment: can you put your answer in the answer section so that I can upvote it.

Comment: You have to tell me WHICH way you want to do this

Comment: I do not know how to extract the data i need above

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have read this column from your database then you have to convert the JSONString into a PHP Datatype. Use `json_decode()` for that like this.

```
$db_col = '{
    "addressCount":"1",
    "link":"https:\/\/maps.googleapis.com\/maps\/api\/staticmap?center=Houston, TX, USA&zoom=16&size=175x124&maptype=roadmap&key=AIzaSyASx6y5K6jD0DATE2S7_UarIvRa3EN-C_M",
    "address":"Houston, TX, USA",
    "zipcode":"77002"
}';

$obj = json_decode($db_col);

echo "Address: {$obj->address} \nZip: {$obj->zipcode}";
```